# How to add more functionality while using existing interfaces in golang?

Tags: go, interface

Suppose I have an interface Foo, and I am adding a struct which needs methods of Foo and few additional methods also. In that case out of following two, which is considered to be best practice? Or if there is some other more appropriate third way, then do suggest.

**Approach 1**

```
type Foo interface {
   methodA()
}

type Bar struct {
}

func (b Bar) methodA () {
   ...
}

func (b Bar) methodB () {
   ...
}
```

**Approach 2**

```
type Foo interface {
   methodA()
}

type Bar struct {
   Foo    // this can be initialized with any concrete implementation of Foo
}

func (b Bar) methodB () {
   ...
}
```

Also, it will be great if it can be pointed out in which scenarios above approaches are better fit for? Thanks!

Comment: In the first approach, if `methodA()` will just wrap a `Foo` e.g. `func (b Bar) methodA() { someFoo.methodA() }`, the added wrapping is not needed anymore and the benefits of approach 2/embedding really shines. Of course this is just my opinion and it really dependent on the situation which is too broad to discuss here.

Comment: Indeed, this depends very much on the actual implementation, and there is no general answer that can be given based on foobar examples. There is nothing wrong with either approach, use the one that makes the most sense in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technical note: first method assures you (besides mistakes in initializing the struct) you can call `methodA` on `Bar`, second one don't because you have to initialize the interface field with something respecting that interface to not have a nil deference error.

Note that using the second method `methodA` is not called on `Bar` **but on the `Foo` embedded object**!

Second method is useful if you have a common implementation that can be shared by many objects and is self containing, i.e. consider you wanna know if an object implements a `Log` method to be sure you can log something with that object: in this case you can have a method that returns a `Logger` and set the interface field with that. Example follows:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Logger interface {
    Log(string)
}

type ConsoleLogger struct {} // See? No external dependencies

func (Cl ConsoleLogger) Log(msg string) {
    fmt.Println(msg)
}

type A1 struct {
    Logger
}

type A2 struct {
    Logger
}

func main() {
    a := A1{ConsoleLogger{}}
    b := A2{ConsoleLogger{}}
    a.Log("Test")
    b.Log("Test")
}
```

Embedding objects is useful for dispatching method calls, remember it's just sintactic sugar in the end so besides passing the containing object you don't have any way to use its fields.

If `Logger` interface had to use outer object (`A1` and `A2`) data in some sort of way than this method would be awkward because you would have to initialize the interface object which would then store some reference to the needed data with a waste of memory in some cases.

IMHO method one forces you to write more code but you are more free in the interface implementation and you can mix the two approaches by embedding a `Logger` and then override the `Log` method in `A1` struct.

Additionally, you **can** nonetheless pass something to build something implementing an interface:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Logger interface {
    Log(string)
}

type ConsoleLogger struct {
    Prepend string // string to prepend to log message
}

func (Cl ConsoleLogger) Log(msg string) {
    fmt.Println(Cl.Prepend + "-" + msg)
}

type A1 struct {
    Logger
}

type A2 struct {
    Logger
}

func (a A2) Log(msg string) { // Overriding implementation
    fmt.Println("In A2")
    a.Logger.Log(msg) // Call the original interface value!
}

func main() {
    a := A1{ConsoleLogger{"A1"}}
    b := A2{ConsoleLogger{"A2"}}
    a.Log("Test")
    b.Log("Test")
}
```